# Documentum error : [DM_STORAGE_E_NOT_ACCESSIBLE]

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, documentum-dfs, documentum-dfc, documentum7.3

I am trying to get the content of all the documents (current version) from a documentum source using the following code

```
IDfSysObject document = (IDfSysObject) session.getObject(new DfId(eachFileMetadata.get(some document id).toString()));
ByteArrayInputStream docContent = document.getContent();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    DfException:: THREAD: Thread-585; MSG: [DM_STORAGE_E_NOT_ACCESSIBLE]error:  "Storage area dist_store_a_store_010 is not currently accessible.  Reason:  errno: 145, message: Connection timed out."; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.docbase.DocbaseExceptionMapper.newException(DocbaseExceptionMapper.java:57)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.MessageEntry.getException(MessageEntry.java:39)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseMessageManager.getException(DocbaseMessageManager.java:137)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.checkForMessages(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:329)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.applyForInt(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:600)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection$6.evaluate(DocbaseConnection.java:1343)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.evaluateRpc(DocbaseConnection.java:1141)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.applyForInt(DocbaseConnection.java:1336)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.docbase.DocbaseApi.makePuller(DocbaseApi.java:630)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.RawPuller.<init>(RawPuller.java:22)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.Session.makePuller(Session.java:3756)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionHandle.makePuller(SessionHandle.java:2468)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.BlockPuller.<init>(BlockPuller.java:27)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.PusherPullerContentAccessor.buildStreamFromContext(PusherPullerContentAccessor.java:40)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.PusherPullerContentAccessor.getStream(PusherPullerContentAccessor.java:28)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentAccessorFactory.getStream(ContentAccessorFactory.java:37)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.Store.getStream(Store.java:63)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.DistributedStore___PROXY.getStream(DistributedStore___PROXY.java)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.Content.getStream(Content.java:185)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.Content___PROXY.getStream(Content___PROXY.java)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentManager.getStream(ContentManager.java:84)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.ContentManager.getStream(ContentManager.java:53)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContentEx3(DfSysObject.java:1952)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContentEx2(DfSysObject.java:1942)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContent(DfSysObject.java:1932)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfDocument___PROXY.getContent(DfDocument___PROXY.java)
```

the above error occured when I am trying to get the content of a document,can anyone please help me??

Comment: You have 40 other questions that is the exact same question, but with different exceptions, firstly please delete other questions and gather the exceptions in one question, secondly do you get those exceptions at once? Also, do you have dqman? And also you need to put r_object_id in the new DfId(...) you know that right?

Comment: i seperated the questions(exceptions) so that they will be very clear and i didn't get all the exceptions at once,I got those exceptions for different documents,yes i have dqman,i know that we have to put the document id in new DfId()  but i have specified as some document id,but how to solve the issue(exception)

Comment: In dqman, select your document with some query like:
select * from asdw where r_object_id='...'
then from the result, right click on the first row of r_object_id column, choose content - export
Are you able to export the document like this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your storage location is not accessible. 
Query your `dm_location` for `storage_01` and find out the `file_system_path` attribute value of this record.

If your content servers are on Unix servers, then check if the mount with `file_system_path` value is available using `df- h` command.

If your content servers are on Windows, then check if you have mapped drive available with `file_system_path` value.

If you see them available, I will recommend to create and access files on this file system. Sometimes there are issues with stale connection on NFS mounts..